# Sharepoint 2010 web service runtime error while accessing through URL

Tags: web-services

First time I am creating web service. I have created two different web service using VS 2010 and after build successfully I have added both the web Service to IIS under layouts folder.

I have dragged the DDL under bin folder as well. I have also done the necessary changes in the web.config file but when I am trying to access through URL, I am getting below error:

[image: WebService]

I have changed the `debug=false` to `debug=true` and `CustomError=on` to `Customerror=off` in web.config but nothing happens.

Please help me out.